# Get Element Text Using xml mini dom python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, minidom

i am trying to get the text of an element using `mini dom`, in the following code , i have also tried `getText()` Method as suggested [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) , but i am unable to get the desired output, following is my code. I dont get the Text value from the element i am trying to work on.

```
import xml.dom.minidom

doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("DL_INVOICE_DETAIL_TCB.xml")
results = doc.getElementsByTagName("G_TRANSACTIONS")
def getText(nodelist):
    rc = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
    return ''.join(rc)
for result in results:
    for element in result.getElementsByTagName("INVOICE_NUMBER"):
        print(element.nodeType)
        print(element.nodeValue)
```

Following is my XML sample

```
<LIST_G_TRANSACTIONS>
    <G_TRANSACTIONS>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>31002</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <TRANSACTION_CLASS>Invoice</TRANSACTION_CLASS>
    </G_TRANSACTIONS>
</LIST_G_TRANSACTIONS>
```

I am using the following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minidom based answer

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml = """\
<LIST_G_TRANSACTIONS>
    <G_TRANSACTIONS>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>31002</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <TRANSACTION_CLASS>Invoice1</TRANSACTION_CLASS>
    </G_TRANSACTIONS>
    <G_TRANSACTIONS>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>31006</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <TRANSACTION_CLASS>Invoice2</TRANSACTION_CLASS>
    </G_TRANSACTIONS>    
</LIST_G_TRANSACTIONS>"""

dom = minidom.parseString(xml)
invoice_numbers = [int(x.firstChild.data) for x in dom.getElementsByTagName("INVOICE_NUMBER")]
print(invoice_numbers)
```

output

```
[31002, 31006]
```

Answer (score 0):

If using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is fine with you, here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<LIST_G_TRANSACTIONS>
    <G_TRANSACTIONS>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>31002</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <TRANSACTION_CLASS>Invoice1</TRANSACTION_CLASS>
    </G_TRANSACTIONS>
    <G_TRANSACTIONS>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>31006</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <TRANSACTION_CLASS>Invoice2</TRANSACTION_CLASS>
    </G_TRANSACTIONS>    
</LIST_G_TRANSACTIONS>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
invoice_numbers = [entry.text for entry in list(root.findall('.//INVOICE_NUMBER'))]
print(invoice_numbers)
```

output

```
['31002', '31006']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i need it via mini dom

Comment: Just to let you know, ElementTree is a core python package and not an external package (just like minidom)